# Notice: __construct is deprecated since version 3.1! Use WP_User_Query instead.

Tags: wordpress, search, edit, author

How do I get around this error? It works and functions correctly but the error shows to the user. If I change WP_User_Search to WP_User_Query it doesn't work. The error goes away but it just doesn't work anymore.

I am trying to override the Author drop down list when you edit a post and remove all the administrator names.

```
// Remove Admins from Post Author Dropdown
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'theme_post_author_override');
function theme_post_author_override($output)
{
 global $post, $user_ID;
  // return if this isn't the theme author override dropdown
  if (!preg_match('/post_author_override/', $output)) return $output;
  // return if we've already replaced the list
  if (preg_match ('/post_author_override_replaced/', $output)) return $output;
  // replaceme wp_dropdown_users
  $admins = getRolesForAuthorList('administrator');
     $output = wp_dropdown_users(array(
        'exclude' => $admins,
        'echo' => '0'
    ));
    // put original back
    $output = preg_replace('/post_author_override_replaced/', 'post_author_override', $output);
  return $output;
}
function getRolesForAuthorList($role) {
    $usersearch = '';
    $userspage = '';
    $wp_user_search = new WP_User_Search($usersearch, $userspage, $role);
    return $wp_user_search->get_results();
}
// Remove Admins from Post Author Dropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array( 'role' => 'Administrator' ));

// Get the results
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
```

from [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Comment: That did not work. I have a new error now... Notice: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to int

Here is the code I have now:

Comment: function getRolesForAuthorList() {
        $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array( 'role' => 'Administrator' ));
        return $wp_user_search->get_results();
    }

Comment: I also see another error too... Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in

Comment: have you tried print_r to display the results you get? + the int error is from the wp_dropdown_users which prrobably expects $admins to be an int, which it won't be since it should return an array i assume

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Could you add the code?